# unknown stresses in double-layer glass window

Tags: pressure, temperature, air, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, stress-strain

I live in cold place where outside temperature drops to -20. Currently, we have -20 and on my window, which is doubled layer glass with trapped air in between, I found a "polarized stress spectrum" (or "ripples" you can say) on the center of glass area (circled below):

[image: see image here]

Earlier, I thought maybe its caused at the "glass making " time, maybe due to stress distribution. But when I touched that glass very gently, causing very slight pressure difference, it caused a big change in position. As you can say 1 cm toward the side where I am exerting pressure. One more thing, when I lit fire flame and take it near to that "elliptical spectrum," it caused dividing that into 2 same shapes which merge after 1 or 2 seconds.

My hypothesis says as its nearly perfect elliptical shape and it can move to side with a slight pressure gives a great change in position. It's caused by trapped air inside BUT here is a question:

If it is caused by air, then how that air caused that visible spectrum? (by exerting pressure on glass surface and due to refraction we see those patterns?An induced stress on glass? What if we don't have something which can refract the light will we still able to get patterns? Please explain it?

Comment: Looks like a [Newton's Rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_rings) type pattern to me

Comment: Roight, but the distance of the glass sheets is cmters. There are 2 sheets with rather good paralell surfaces each (today most windows are float glass). There are a lot of interference phenomena which are possible. One needed to know the whole optical system: light source, angle of reflection point/direction of eye/camera.

Comment: There's a good chance this is due to a coating on the glass itself. Do you have any manufacturer's data to indicate whether or not a "low-E" type layer was applied?

Comment: @Georg yeah i understand your point about interference phenomenon but just want to ask is it cause of pressure and internal air condition and glass is just a refraction medium ??

Comment: @CarlWitthoft no i dont have any additional data from manufacturer but today i saw maybe glass is providing refractive index and this all is just a internal state of air pressure due to huge temprature difference or what glass is letting us able to see it